# CSS/JS: Targeting :nth-child consistant across 2 parent elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say we have a setup like this:

```css
.col:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: red;
}

/* Style the div's for testing */
div.row {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div.col {
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"><!-- The .col's in this row are dynamically generated -->
  <div class="col 1"></div>
  <div class="col 2"></div>
  <div class="col 3"></div>
  <div class="col 4"></div>
  <div class="col 5"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col 1"></div>
  <div class="col 2"></div>
  <div class="col 3"></div>
  <div class="col 4"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1L4rodh4/

Now... the `Nth selector` is working as it should. The problem is that I want to get the elements styled consistently. so that it appears to be seamless between the 2 `.row`'s. The `.col`'s in the first `.row` are dynamically generated and could end up being `even` or `odd`.

Please ask me for clarification if I wasn't clear. I couldn't find any information about this elsewhere. This is something that seems so simple, yet it seems to be impossible.

Is there a better way of doing this, or am I stuck?

---

I understand I could use JS to get the number of "col"'s in the first "row" and change the selector in the second row. That just seems way too hack-ish for this though.

EDIT: I will accept a JS solution.

---

The following is a working example of how this can be done with a simple plain JS script, based on the code in the selected answer below.

```js
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('.table.js-fix .tr');
for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
  cols[i].classList.add(i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
}
```

```css
.table.js-fix .tr:nth-child(2n + 1), /* :nth-child fallback */
.table.js-fix .tr.even {
 background: red;
}
.table.js-fix .tr.odd {
 background: #fff;
}

/* Style for testing */
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.tr {
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"><!-- The .tr in this row is just used as a thead -->
  <div class="col">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="tr">Section Title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row"><!-- The .tr's in this row are dynamically generated -->
  <div class="col">
    <div class="table js-fix">
      <div class="tr"></div>
      <div class="tr"></div>
      <div class="tr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row"><!-- There will always be 5 .tr's in this row -->
  <div class="col">
    <div class="table js-fix">
      <div class="tr"></div>
      <div class="tr"></div>
      <div class="tr"></div>
      <div class="tr"></div>
      <div class="tr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle with the above example: https://jsfiddle.net/n12h70j6/

Comment: If you know that the number or cols in each row will always be odd, the solution is easy: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1L4rodh4/1/ but you need something more flexible I presume?

Comment: @MrLister, the first "row" is dynamically generated [with PHP based on a bunch of factors], so it could be even or odd.

Comment: I do realise that; that's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. But there is no "element that has an odd number of children" type selector in CSS, so I'm afraid there's no CSS-only solution.

Comment: This would be quite easy using flexbox.

Comment: @torazaburo, please expand, I'm open to anything.

Comment: @MrLister, it's looking like I'd have to resort to JS.

Comment: Is it necessary to split those rows into two separate `div`s? You could also just add a class to the last element of the first table like `.last` and style it accordingly. You can however not depend the nth-child on the number of children of another element

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, it is necessary, I just showed what's necessary for the question above. I've tried everything to get it to work without having to split everything up.

Comment: @Matthew Hey, if the rows are generated dynamically, you can count the number of cols on the server side and assign a class to them accordingly. `if (cols.count&1) then row.class += "oddcols"` and respond to `.oddcols` in the CSS. The you won't have to resort to JavaScript.

Comment: @Mr Lister but there exists a hack though. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with CSS.
See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1L4rodh4/3/) or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1L4rodh4/4/).

```
.col:first-child:nth-last-child(even) ~ .col:nth-child(2n + 1),
.col:first-child:nth-last-child(even){
  background-color: red;
}

.col:first-child:nth-last-child(odd) ~ .col:nth-child(2n + 2){
  background-color: red;
}
```

This checks if the number of children are even or odd and styles them appropriately.

**Update**: Inspite of what it might look like. This will not work for cases when a parent with odd number of children directly follows another parent with odd number of children (which was the whole point). However I am leaving this here for someone else to get ideas running in their heads.

Since it is still an answer, CSS alone cannot do this, so one must resort to javascript / jQuery.

This could be one way to do this with plain JS

```
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('.col');
for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
    cols[i].classList.add(i % 2 == 0 ? 'some-class' : 'alternate-class');
```

Comment: Noooooo waaayyyy! I was looking at the ~ thing a while ago... what does this even do? This is amazing! I had lost all hope lol

Comment: How did you come across this? And could you explain a little about ~ to me, please?

Comment: This looks promising, and you have my upvote, but it needs work. If the number of cols is even, the top col has a different colour than when it is odd.

Comment: @Matthew: `~` is the general sibling selector, which means it will select the sibling elements wherever it is, as long as it's still the sibling. https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: `~` is the any subsequent sibling selector. So essentially you are asking for all subsequent siblings of a `.col` `first-child` which is `an even child when counted from the end`, and itself. The second one does the same for the `odd` ones.

Comment: @deathlock it should be noted that `~` only targets subsequent siblings, not the ones that have already appeared before the target.

Comment: @Mr Lister I presume you mean styling, starting from the odd one. Indeed a good observation. I'll update my post.

Comment: Obviously you answered the question and it's great, now I'm just trying to get the code to work with my set up. Here's my more realistic Fiddle with the code displaying the issue that I'm currently experiencing: https://jsfiddle.net/hssj06br/ - any ideas?

Comment: But it still does not address the situation where a parent with odd number of children follows the other. I accept, that it still needs some work.

Comment: Mhmm, I'm a little stuck here, the second row actually will always have an odd number of rows, so it causes it to be off: https://jsfiddle.net/ps9n55a0/ - well it's a good start haha

Comment: You're going to need to provide a working example, because I'm quite sure this can't and won't work.

Comment: @Matthew Any particular reason for accepting an answer which doesn't work?

Comment: @torazaburo I think the answer was accepted before finding out the shortcoming. If there's a way to unaccept the answer, let's do that for the time being while we look any alternate approach.

Comment: @torazaburo done, and yes like Nikhil said, I had accepted it before we were done testing the solution. It seemed to be fine except for that one scenario, unfortunately.

Comment: @NikhilGirraj, here's what I'm thinking... you've made it so that as long as the second group is even, the whole thing seems to work out, so is it possible to do the opposite... that the second group would be odd, and it works out? Maybe there isn't a way to properly answer my question, but maybe there's a useful way of going around it?

Comment: I've accepted the answer now because it does provide the attempt with CSS, a solution with JS, and the conclusion as to why it cannot be done with CSS alone. (I was also thinking of queryselectorall!)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no CSS-only way of doing this.

The reason is that CSS rules can only be qualified based on directly preceding children, or ancestors. In you case, you want to qualify the second group based on what is **inside** the previous sibling (the first `<div>` group).

The only way to handle this is by means of something like adding a class to the first `<div>` that indicates whether it has an even or odd number of children.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with how CSS functions, but specifically how this rule functions. :nth-child is specifically targeting the child, so the selector needs a parent element... where as other elements of CSS like background-color can just be stuck on every DIV. So, it just makes sense that you should be able to apply a style like that to every other div, since it's able to select all of them. Yet for this specific case, it's limited to an element within a parent, it just seems so silly.

Comment: No, the child-related pseudo-classes do not need a parent element. `:nth-child(even)` is a perfectly good selector all by itself.